# Bib file on latex

Tags: bibliographies

I have a `bib` file called `putascitas.bib` (generated through Mendeley in Bibdesk).

Now, what do I have to do to just get the references in the end of the document? Nothing I do seems to work.

Thanks.

Comment: [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162) is often a good starting point for diagnosing basic bibliography/citation issues.

Comment: `\bibliography{filename}` doesn't mean that everything in the bib-file is printed automatically, only entries in the `.bib` file that are cited with a command like `\cite{<citation key>}` are put there. If you do want all entries in the bib file to be printed even if they're not cited, add `\nocite{*}` to your document.